# How to show a "linked from site X" placeholder instead of actual photo?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I’m hosting a bunch of photos on Amazon S3 and also running Amazon CloudFront for them. Also, I’m running a custom domain name.
Now, in case someone tries to embed the image to another website, I’d like to show a "This image is hosted on domain X" instead of the actual image.

Is this possible with the current setup I’ve described?

Whether this is a good idea or not, is not really a question, I just need to see if it’s even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloudfront does not support the referrer header, so you can't directly do this. One approach to dealing with hotlinking though, is to generate [signed URLs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html?r=2013) that expire after a short time. Essentially, with a dynamic page, you make all your Cloudfront content private, and then use a signed URL to embed the image in your page. The signed URL grants access to the content - either for a short period of time, or for a particular IP address. This essentially makes hotlinking impractical - as someone would need to constantly scrape your site for the new, valid, URLs. Of course, this has implications on caching. You could, alternatively, have the URL valid for a little over a day and regenerate the URL daily, instead of every page load.

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable, thanks for the answer and I’ll try it out in the future if I really need to go down that path.

Answer (score 1):

If CloudFront supports request rewriting based on the `Referer:` header, then yes. If it doesn't, then you'll need to put a web server that does between the public and your images. Apache/nginx both support this, as do most others that I'm aware of.